# Get all cells in a column containing a specific formula where the value is X

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen variations of this question asked before, but when trying to bring the solutions together to get the result I am looking for, there ends up being something that just isn't clicking.

I want to go through all the cells in column `A` where they contained the "CalcText()" formula. If they do contain the formula, then they match if they contain a value of `Z`. If they all do, then the user-defined function reports a "Match", otherwise there is "No Match". My code is below:

```
Function IsAMatch() As String
Dim Cell As Range
'Look at each cell in the A column
For Each Cell In Range("A:A")
    'Check if the cell does not contain the wanted text
    If (InStr(0, "CalcText", Cell, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        If (InStr(0, "Z", Cell.Value2, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            IsAMatch = "No Match"
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
IsAMatch = "Match"
End Function
```

What I think I am doing is looping through every cell in column `A` and checking if it does not contain the wanted text. However, the result of the function is `#Value` and not either of the text result strings.

EXAMPLE:

Cell A1 contains the formula `CalcText()` which evaluates to `Z`.

Comment: Do you have cells in column `A` *without* the formula and *with* a value of `Z`? If no, then why bother checking for the formula?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad good point, it is possible a cell would contain `Z` and not the formula. However, I only care about the cells containing the formula

Comment: What happens if you record a macro to search for text in formula and amend it? ;)

Comment: You may also want to see [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/). Once you record the macro, use `What:="CalcText"` and `LookIn:=xlFormulas` and `LookAt:=xlPart`. This way you do not need to loop through every cell in column A ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Public Function IsAMatch()

Application.Volatile

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = Application.Caller.Parent

IsAMatch = "No Match"

For Each Cell In Ws.Range("A1:A" & Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) ' only scan used range of A:A
    If (InStr(1, Cell.Formula, "calctext", vbTextCompare) > 0) And (InStr(1, Cell.Value2, "z", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        IsAMatch = "Match"
        Exit For ' added as per comment from .nomad - Exit Function could be used if no other work required.
    End If
Next Cell

End Function
```

I've added `Application.Volatile` to get it to recalculate every time. Not sure if it's needed in your scenario though.

Comment: You  should be able to exit the function after the first match has been found, since finding additional ones will not change the result

Comment: Good spot @cybernetic.nomad . `Exit For` added as I suspect this may be only a part of OPs actual code.

Answer (score 0):

WHy not just use the `find` and `replace` function, something like this

```
Dim r As Excel.Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(What:="=CalcText()", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Set r = r.Find("z", r.Cells(1, 1), xlValues, XlLookAt.xlWhole)

r.Value = "NEW VAL"
```

Comment: Yes `.Find` is a more efficient approach :) But instead of `What:="=CalcText()"` use `What:="CalcText"` and handle the case when no result is found. Also you need to use `.Findnext` if the first match doesnt return the correct result. One last thing.. The user does not want to replace anything :)

Comment: See the link that I posted below the question. That will get you started :)